# Progress Bar for Excel

Tags: vba, excel, user-interface

Any future updates can be found at [Excel-VBA-ProgressBar](https://github.com/cristianbuse/Excel-VBA-ProgressBar)

---

### What I've been using so far

For the last 6 years I've been using a progress form which I wrote in VBA using just Windows API calls. The code (not for review) is here: [gist](https://gist.github.com/cristianbuse/db15757131f38f3e33f684669e2b3521). It has a small demo as well.

It worked because there was no `DoEvents` call. So, although the form is not modal by any means, the user cannot interact with Excel itself unless stepping through code, and the bar still updates visually without freezing. I also liked that the entire code is in a single class module and never crashed.

However, there are 2 main drawbacks:

1. It only works on Windows, not Mac
2. The user cannot cancel the form as there are no events. This could be done using subclassing but I definitely don't want to go into that rabbit hole - I don't want any crashes due to Stop button being pressed or system timeouts.

There are also smaller issues like flickering.

### What I wanted to achieve

I wanted a progress bar that would solve the next points:

1. Works on both Win and Mac
2. The user can cancel the displayed form via the X button, if allowed
3. The user can cancel via the Esc key, if allowed
4. The form displayed can be Modal but also Modeless, as needed
5. The progress bar would call a 'worker' routine
6. The 'worker' routine called would be able to return a value if it's a `Function`
7. The 'worker' routine would accept a variable number of parameters and would be able to change them `ByRef` if needed
8. The 'worker' routine does not need to accept the progress bar instance at a specific position in the parameter list, or at all (for whatever reason - a global variable could be used, although I would not recommend)
9. The 'worker' routine can be a macro in a workbook or a method on an object
10. The main progress bar class doesn't need a global instance nor a factory
11. Easy customizable properties
12. Has the ability to show how much time has elapsed and an approximation of how much time is left which can be useful for tasks where steps are almost equal but also the ability to turn the time off when not needed or inaccurate
13. The number of classes/modules is at a minimum. Would have preferred just one as the gist mentioned above but that's not realistic in plain VBA with no API. For example `CreateObject("Forms.Form.1")` does indeed create a form but it cannot be displayed. So, realistically, a class module and an actual `UserForm` module are needed at the very least
14. The userform module has a minimum of code. Basically, just events, that are going to get raised but nothing else and no other logic whatsoever
15. The userform module has no design time controls. This would make it easy to just create a new form in 3 steps: insert new form, rename, add events code. So, controls added at runtime
16. No interfaces because of [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63989741/bug-when-using-interfaces-on-larger-projects). To be honest I never got to refactor those particular large projects (mentioned in the link) and it might be the module size that is the issue (as suggested by @MathieuGuindon). But then there's also number 13 above - I prefer less modules

### What's already available

On a quick search, a lot of progress bars/forms popped-up but most of them were using Win APIs which defeated the number 1 issue I had - not working on Mac. Plus, I have my own API (old an ugly) API implementation as in the mentioned gist.

And then countless posts using a Modeless userform which defeated the number 4 point raised above - need both Modal and Modeless.

And then I found the excellent article [The Reusable Progress Indicator](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/01/12/progress-indicator/) written by @MathieuGuindon. I remember reading it in a hurry when it was first posted about 3 years ago but back then the [gist](https://gist.github.com/cristianbuse/db15757131f38f3e33f684669e2b3521) I linked was enough for what I was doing. Admittedly the article is rather old and the author mentioned in a few other places and articles that he needs to revisit the progress indicator. Regardless, I've read it carefully and I loved the idea of displaying a Modal form which then raises an `Activated` event. That's the spark I needed to start implementing my own form that solves all the other points raised above. Many thanks to the author!

### Implementation

**Userform**

Any new userform is fine. No controls are needed and the form can be of any size. Needed:

1. Then userform name must be `ProgressForm`
2. The code inside the form is:

```
Option Explicit

Public Event Activate()
Public Event QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    RaiseEvent Activate
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    RaiseEvent QueryClose(Cancel, CloseMode)
End Sub
```

The form itself can be shown independently but is rather useless on it's own.

**Reference**

In order to achieve point 7 (variable number of parameters which preserve the `ByRef` flag) I needed a way to safely copy a `ParamArray` into a regular array. Unfortunately that cannot be done natively so I am using the function `CloneParamArray` from my own repository [VBA-MemoryTools](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-MemoryTools). I could argue that the cloning is somewhat natively as all the supporting methods copy memory natively via `ByRef` Variants but that's not important. So, [LibMemory](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-MemoryTools/blob/master/src/LibMemory.bas) bas module is needed because otherwise no arguments could be changed by reference while a Modal form is displayed.

**Class**

The `ProgressBar` class code:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents m_form As ProgressForm
Private m_allowCancel As Boolean
Private m_cancelled As Boolean
Private m_currentValue As Double
Private m_isAutoCentered As Boolean
Private m_isRunning As Boolean
Private m_procedure As String
Private m_result As Variant
Private m_showTime As Boolean
Private m_showType As FormShowConstants
Private m_startTime As Date
Private m_targetBook As Workbook
Private m_targetObj As Object
Private m_args() As Variant

'Controls
Private m_info1 As MSForms.Label
Private m_info2 As MSForms.Label
Private m_barFrame As MSForms.Frame
Private m_bar As MSForms.Label
Private m_elapsed As MSForms.Label
Private m_remaining As MSForms.Label
Private m_percent As MSForms.Label
Private WithEvents m_escButton As MSForms.CommandButton

#If Mac Then
#ElseIf VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe _
Function rtcCallByName Lib "VBE7.DLL" (ByVal targetObj As Object _
                                     , ByVal procNamePtr As LongPtr _
                                     , ByVal vCallType As VbCallType _
                                     , ByRef args() As Any _
                                     , Optional ByVal lcid As Long) As Variant
#Else
Private Declare _
Function rtcCallByName Lib "msvbvm60" (ByVal targetObj As Object _
                                     , ByVal procNamePtr As Long _
                                     , ByVal vCallType As VbCallType _
                                     , ByRef args() As Any _
                                     , Optional ByVal lcid As Long) As Variant
#End If

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'Class events
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_form = New ProgressForm
    BuildForm
    With Me
        .AllowCancel = False
        .Caption = "Progress..."
        .Info1 = "Please wait..."
        .Info2 = vbNullString
        .ShowTime = False
        .ShowType = vbModal
        .CenterOnApplication
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    TryHideForm
    Set m_form = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub TryHideForm()
    On Error Resume Next 'Avoid error 402
    m_form.Hide
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

'*******************************************************************************
'Builds the necessary controls and alignment at runtime
'*******************************************************************************
Private Sub BuildForm()
    Const progIDLabel As String = "Forms.Label.1"
    Const progIDFrame As String = "Forms.Frame.1"
    Const progIDButton As String = "Forms.CommandButton.1"
    Const sideValue As Single = 6
    '
    m_form.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    m_form.Font.Size = 8.25
    m_form.Width = 300
    '
    Set m_info1 = m_form.Controls.Add(progIDLabel)
    CastToControl(m_info1).Move sideValue, sideValue
    TextAlignLabel m_info1, False, True, fmTextAlignLeft
    '
    Set m_info2 = m_form.Controls.Add(progIDLabel)
    CastToControl(m_info2).Move sideValue, CastToControl(m_info1).Top + 12
    TextAlignLabel m_info2, False, True, fmTextAlignLeft
    '
    Set m_barFrame = m_form.Controls.Add(progIDFrame)
    CastToControl(m_barFrame).Move sideValue, CastToControl(m_info2).Top + 15 _
        , m_form.InsideWidth - sideValue * 2, 15
    m_barFrame.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
    '
    Set m_bar = m_barFrame.Controls.Add(progIDLabel)
    CastToControl(m_bar).Move 0, 0, 15, 15
    m_bar.BackColor = &HC07000
    '
    Set m_elapsed = m_form.Controls.Add(progIDLabel)
    CastToControl(m_elapsed).Move sideValue, CastToControl(m_barFrame).Top + 18
    TextAlignLabel m_elapsed, False, True, fmTextAlignLeft
    '
    Set m_remaining = m_form.Controls.Add(progIDLabel)
    CastToControl(m_remaining).Move sideValue, CastToControl(m_elapsed).Top + 12
    TextAlignLabel m_remaining, False, True, fmTextAlignLeft
    With CastToControl(m_remaining)
        m_form.Height = .Top + .Height + sideValue
    End With
    With m_form
       .Height = .Height * 2 - .InsideHeight
    End With
    '
    Set m_percent = m_form.Controls.Add(progIDLabel)
    CastToControl(m_percent).Move CastToControl(m_barFrame).Width _
        + sideValue - 60, CastToControl(m_elapsed).Top, 60
    TextAlignLabel m_percent, False, False, fmTextAlignRight
    '
    Set m_escButton = m_form.Controls.Add(progIDButton)
    With CastToControl(m_escButton)
        .Cancel = True 'Allows for the form to be closed by pressing the Esc key
        .Move 0, 0, 0, 0
    End With
End Sub
Private Function CastToControl(ByVal c As MSForms.Control) As MSForms.Control
    Set CastToControl = c
End Function
Private Sub TextAlignLabel(ByVal labelControl As MSForms.Label _
                         , ByVal wordWrapValue As Boolean _
                         , ByVal autoSizeValue As Boolean _
                         , ByVal textAlignValue As fmTextAlign)
    With labelControl
        .WordWrap = wordWrapValue
        .AutoSize = autoSizeValue
        .TextAlign = textAlignValue
    End With
End Sub

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'Form/Control events
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Private Sub m_form_Activate()
    If m_showType = vbModal Then RunProcedure
End Sub
Private Sub m_form_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then 'User pressed X button
        Cancel = True
        OnCancel
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub m_escButton_Click()
    OnCancel
End Sub
Private Sub OnCancel()
    If Not m_allowCancel Then Exit Sub
    '
    If MsgBox(Prompt:="Are you sure you want to cancel?" _
            , Buttons:=vbQuestion + vbYesNo _
            , Title:="Please confirm" _
    ) = vbYes Then
        m_form.Hide
        m_cancelled = True
    End If
End Sub

'===============================================================================
'Caption text
'===============================================================================
Public Property Get Caption() As String
    Caption = m_form.Caption
End Property
Public Property Let Caption(ByVal formCaption As String)
    m_form.Caption = formCaption
    Refresh
End Property

'===============================================================================
'Info1 text
'===============================================================================
Public Property Get Info1() As String
    Info1 = m_info1.Caption
End Property
Public Property Let Info1(ByVal info1Label As String)
    m_info1.Caption = info1Label
    Refresh
End Property

'===============================================================================
'Info2 text
'===============================================================================
Public Property Get Info2() As String
    Info2 = m_info2.Caption
End Property
Public Property Let Info2(ByVal info2Label As String)
    m_info2.Caption = info2Label
    Refresh
End Property

'===============================================================================
'Color of the bar
'===============================================================================
Public Property Get BarColor() As Long
    BarColor = m_bar.BackColor
End Property
Public Property Let BarColor(ByVal colorCode As Long)
    m_bar.BackColor = colorCode
    Refresh
End Property

'===============================================================================
'Color of the frame (bar background)
'===============================================================================
Public Property Get BarBackColor() As Long
    BarBackColor = m_barFrame.BackColor
End Property
Public Property Let BarBackColor(ByVal colorCode As Long)
     m_barFrame.BackColor = colorCode
     Refresh
End Property

'===============================================================================
'Enables/disables the X button on the progress form
'===============================================================================
Public Property Get AllowCancel() As Boolean
    AllowCancel = m_allowCancel
End Property
Public Property Let AllowCancel(ByVal canCancel As Boolean)
     m_allowCancel = canCancel
End Property

'===============================================================================
'Can be modal or modeless
'===============================================================================
Public Property Get ShowType() As FormShowConstants
    ShowType = m_showType
End Property
Public Property Let ShowType(ByVal formShowType As FormShowConstants)
    If formShowType <> vbModal Then formShowType = vbModeless 'Restrict value
    m_showType = formShowType
End Property

'===============================================================================
'Enables/disables the time labels
'===============================================================================
Public Property Get ShowTime() As Boolean
    ShowTime = m_showTime
End Property
Public Property Let ShowTime(ByVal displayTime As Boolean)
    m_showTime = displayTime
    m_elapsed.Visible = m_showTime
    m_remaining.Visible = m_showTime
    Refresh
End Property

'===============================================================================
'Indicates if the X button on the progress form was pressed
'===============================================================================
Public Property Get WasCancelled() As Boolean
    WasCancelled = m_cancelled
End Property

'===============================================================================
'Vertical position
'===============================================================================
Public Property Get Top() As Single
    Top = m_form.Top
End Property
Public Property Let Top(ByVal topValue As Single)
    m_form.Top = topValue
    m_isAutoCentered = False
End Property

'===============================================================================
'Horizontal position
'===============================================================================
Public Property Get Left() As Single
    Left = m_form.Left
End Property
Public Property Let Left(ByVal leftValue As Single)
    m_form.Left = leftValue
    m_isAutoCentered = False
End Property

'*******************************************************************************
'Utility for positioning
'*******************************************************************************
Public Sub CenterOnApplication()
    If Application.WindowState = xlMinimized Then Exit Sub
    '
    Dim leftPosition As Single
    Dim topPosition As Single
    '
    With Application
        leftPosition = .Left + (.Width - m_form.Width) / 2
        If leftPosition < .Left Then leftPosition = .Left
        '
        topPosition = .Top + (.Height - m_form.Height) / 2
        If topPosition < .Top Then topPosition = .Top
    End With
    With m_form
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Left = leftPosition
        .Top = topPosition
    End With
    m_isAutoCentered = True
End Sub

'===============================================================================
'Size
'===============================================================================
Public Property Get Height() As Single
    Height = m_form.Height
End Property
Public Property Get Width() As Single
    Width = m_form.Width
End Property
Public Property Let Width(ByVal widthValue As Single)
    Const minWidth As Single = 180
    Const maxWidth As Single = 450
    Dim finalWidth As Single: finalWidth = widthValue
    Dim offsetValue As Single
    '
    If finalWidth < minWidth Then finalWidth = minWidth
    If finalWidth > maxWidth Then finalWidth = maxWidth
    If finalWidth = m_form.Width Then Exit Property
    offsetValue = finalWidth - m_form.Width
    '
    m_form.Width = finalWidth
    m_barFrame.Width = m_barFrame.Width + offsetValue
    m_percent.Left = m_percent.Left + offsetValue
    If m_isAutoCentered Then m_form.Left = m_form.Left - offsetValue / 2
End Property

'*******************************************************************************
'Self-instance
'*******************************************************************************
Public Function Self() As ProgressBar
    Set Self = Me
End Function

'===============================================================================
'Current progress value
'===============================================================================
Public Property Get Value() As Double
    Value = m_currentValue
End Property
Public Property Let Value(ByVal percentValue As Double)
    If percentValue < 0 Or percentValue > 1 Then Exit Property
    m_currentValue = percentValue
    '
    m_bar.Width = m_currentValue * m_barFrame.InsideWidth
    m_percent.Caption = "Done: " & Format$(m_currentValue, "0%")
    '
    Refresh
End Property

'*******************************************************************************
'Updates the time and allows for events so that the form is updated visually
'*******************************************************************************
Private Sub Refresh()
    If m_isRunning Then
        UpdateTime
        DoEvents
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub UpdateTime()
    If Not m_showTime Then Exit Sub
    If m_currentValue = 0 Then
        m_elapsed.Caption = vbNullString
        m_remaining.Caption = vbNullString
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '
    Dim elapsedTime As Date
    Dim remainingTime As Date
    '
    elapsedTime = VBA.Now - m_startTime
    remainingTime = elapsedTime / m_currentValue * (1 - m_currentValue)
    '
    UpdateTimeLabel m_elapsed, elapsedTime, "Elapsed time: "
    UpdateTimeLabel m_remaining, remainingTime, "Remaining time: "
End Sub
Private Sub UpdateTimeLabel(ByVal labelControl As MSForms.Label _
                          , ByVal timeValue As Date _
                          , ByVal prefix As String)
    Dim labelValue As String: labelValue = prefix
    If timeValue > 1 Then labelValue = labelValue & Int(CDbl(timeValue)) & "d "
    labelControl.Caption = labelValue & Format$(timeValue, "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub

'*******************************************************************************
'Runs a macro in a standard module
'*******************************************************************************
Public Function RunMacro(ByVal targetBook As Workbook _
                       , ByVal procedure As String _
                       , ParamArray args() As Variant) As Variant
    If m_isRunning Then Exit Function
    Dim methodName As String: methodName = TypeName(Me) & ".RunMacro"
    '
    If procedure = vbNullString Then
        Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Invalid procedure name"
    ElseIf targetBook Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise 91, methodName, "Workbook not set"
    ElseIf UBound(args) >= LBound(args) Then 'Save arguments for async use
        CloneParamArray args(0), UBound(args) + 1, m_args 'ByRef is preserved!
    Else
        m_args = Array()
    End If
    '
    LetSet(RunMacro) = Run(procedure, targetBook, Nothing)
End Function

'*******************************************************************************
'Runs a method of a given object
'*******************************************************************************
Public Function RunObjMethod(ByVal targetObject As Object _
                           , ByVal procedure As String _
                           , ParamArray args() As Variant) As Variant
    If m_isRunning Then Exit Function
    Dim methodName As String: methodName = TypeName(Me) & ".RunObjMethod"
    '
    If procedure = vbNullString Then
        Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Invalid procedure name"
    ElseIf targetObject Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise 91, methodName, "Object not set"
    ElseIf UBound(args) >= LBound(args) Then 'Save arguments for async use
        CloneParamArray args(0), UBound(args) + 1, m_args 'ByRef is preserved!
    Else
        m_args = Array()
    End If
    '
    LetSet(RunObjMethod) = Run(procedure, Nothing, targetObject)
End Function

'*******************************************************************************
'Runs a method:
'   - in a standard module if 'targetBook' is provided
'   - on an object if 'targetObject' is provided
'*******************************************************************************
Private Function Run(ByVal procedure As String _
                   , ByVal targetBook As Workbook _
                   , ByVal targetObject As Object) As Variant
    m_procedure = procedure
    Set m_targetBook = targetBook
    Set m_targetObj = targetObject
    '
    m_isRunning = True
    m_cancelled = False
    Value = 0
    '
    m_form.Show m_showType
    If m_showType = vbModeless Then
        RunProcedure
    Else 'vbModal. RunProcedure was already executed via Form_Activate event
    End If
    LetSet(Run) = m_result
End Function

'*******************************************************************************
'Utility - assigns a variant to another variant
'*******************************************************************************
Private Property Let LetSet(ByRef result As Variant, ByRef v As Variant)
    If IsObject(v) Then Set result = v Else result = v
End Property

'*******************************************************************************
'Runs the actual method
'*******************************************************************************
Private Sub RunProcedure()
    m_startTime = Now()
    '
    Dim cKey As XlEnableCancelKey: cKey = Application.EnableCancelKey
    If cKey <> xlDisabled Then Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    '
    On Error GoTo Clean
    If m_targetObj Is Nothing Then
        RunOnBook
    Else
        #If Mac Then
            RunOnObject m_args
        #Else
            LetSet(m_result) = rtcCallByName(targetObj:=m_targetObj _
                                           , procNamePtr:=StrPtr(m_procedure) _
                                           , vCallType:=VbMethod _
                                           , args:=m_args)
        #End If
    End If
Clean:
    If cKey <> xlDisabled Then Application.EnableCancelKey = cKey
    m_isRunning = False
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        TryHideForm 'Protection if multiple progress bars are displayed
    Else
        m_form.Hide
        Err.Raise Err.Number, TypeName(Me) & ".RunProcedure"
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub RunOnBook(Optional ByVal Missing As Variant)
    Const maxRunArgs As Long = 30
    Dim argsCount As Long: argsCount = UBound(m_args) + 1
    Dim i As Long
    '
    ReDim Preserve m_args(0 To maxRunArgs - 1)
    For i = argsCount To UBound(m_args)
        m_args(i) = Missing
    Next i
    '
    LetSet(m_result) = Application.Run(FullProcedureName() _
        , m_args(0), m_args(1), m_args(2), m_args(3), m_args(4) _
        , m_args(5), m_args(6), m_args(7), m_args(8), m_args(9) _
        , m_args(10), m_args(11), m_args(12), m_args(13), m_args(14) _
        , m_args(15), m_args(16), m_args(17), m_args(18), m_args(19) _
        , m_args(20), m_args(21), m_args(22), m_args(23), m_args(24) _
        , m_args(25), m_args(26), m_args(27), m_args(28), m_args(29))
End Sub
Private Function FullProcedureName() As String
    FullProcedureName = "'" & m_targetBook.Name & "'!" & m_procedure
End Function
#If Mac Then
Private Sub RunOnObject(ByRef args() As Variant)
    Dim o As Object: Set o = m_targetObj
    Dim p As String: p = m_procedure
    Dim v As VbCallType: v = VbMethod
    '
    Select Case UBound(args) - LBound(args) + 1
    Case 0: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v)
    Case 1: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0))
    Case 2: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1))
    Case 3: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2))
    Case 4: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3))
    Case 5: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4))
    Case 6: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5))
    Case 7: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6))
    Case 8: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7))
    Case 9: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8))
    Case 10: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9))
    Case 11: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10))
    Case 12: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11))
    Case 13: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12))
    Case 14: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13))
    Case 15: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14))
    Case 16: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15))
    Case 17: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16))
    Case 18: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17))
    Case 19: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18))
    Case 20: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19))
    Case 21: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19), args(20))
    Case 22: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19), args(20), args(21))
    Case 23: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19), args(20), args(21), args(22))
    Case 24: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19), args(20), args(21), args(22), args(23))
    Case 25: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19), args(20), args(21), args(22), args(23), args(24))
    Case 26: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19), args(20), args(21), args(22), args(23), args(24), args(25))
    Case 27: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19), args(20), args(21), args(22), args(23), args(24), args(25), args(26))
    Case 28: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19), args(20), args(21), args(22), args(23), args(24), args(25), args(26), args(27))
    Case 29: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19), args(20), args(21), args(22), args(23), args(24), args(25), args(26), args(27), args(28))
    Case Else: LetSet(m_result) = CallByName(o, p, v, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), args(18), args(19), args(20), args(21), args(22), args(23), args(24), args(25), args(26), args(27), args(28), args(29))
    End Select
End Sub
#End If
```

Apologies to those who cannot stand big banners above method definitions. it's just my own preference.

### Demo

Assuming a 'worker' code routine in a standard bas module:

```
Public Function DoWork(ByVal progress As ProgressBar, ByRef stepCount As Long) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To stepCount
        progress.Info2 = "Running " & i & " out of " & stepCount
        progress.Value = i / stepCount
        If progress.WasCancelled Then
            'Clean-up code here
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    DoWork = True
End Function
```

The call to `RunMacro` can be as simple as:

```
Public Sub ProgressBarTest()
    With New ProgressBar
        Debug.Print .RunMacro(ThisWorkbook, "DoWork", .Self, 2000)
    End With
End Sub
```

Or, can be more customized:

```
Public Sub ProgressBarTest()
    With New ProgressBar
        .Info1 = "Please wait..."
        .AllowCancel = True
        .BarColor = &H4D6A00
        .ShowTime = True
        .ShowType = vbModeless
        Debug.Print .RunMacro(ThisWorkbook, "DoWork", .Self, 2000)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

If, we want to call a similar routine in `Class1`:

```
Public Function DoWork(ByVal progress As ProgressBar, ByRef stepCount As Long) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To stepCount
        progress.Info2 = "Running " & i & " out of " & stepCount
        progress.Value = i / stepCount
        If progress.WasCancelled Then Exit Function
    Next
    DoWork = True
End Function
```

then we use the `RunObjMethod` method:

```
Public Sub ProgressBarTest()
    With New ProgressBar
        .Info1 = "Please wait..."
        .AllowCancel = True
        .BarColor = &H4D6A00
        .ShowTime = True
        .ShowType = vbModeless
        Debug.Print .RunObjMethod(New Class1, "DoWork", .Self, 2000)
    End With
End Sub
```

### Misc

Here is a list of decisions I took and why:

1. In both the `RunMacro` and `RunObjMethod`, the procedure name parameter is after the book/class object parameter so that the variable number of arguments follow nicely after the method name as it would in a regular call. Feels more natural than having the name first
2. I have not fixed the position of the progress bar instance as a parameter for the 'worker' method. It can actually be omitted as an argument entirely but then the 'worker' would not be able to update the bar unless using a global variable - which is bad practice. Just wanted to have full flexibility for the user
3. I did not want to have a global instance of the `ProgressBar` class that has a factory. I did not consider it to be necessary.
4. When calling `Application.Run` I've made sure that I pass the maximum number of parameters (30) while making sure that the extra parameters are set to the special value `Missing` so that I avoid a nasty long `Select Case`
5. On Windows, instead of calling `CallByName` I call `rtcCallByName` (defined on VBE7.dll) which allows me to pass the array of arguments as one argument. On Mac, unfortunately, I had to create a big `Select Case` (see `RunOnObject` method). It would be great if someone knows a way to make `rtcCallByName` work on a Mac or maybe another/better way to achieve the same result
6. Running multiple `RunMacro` and `RunObjMethod` on the same instance works without the need to create a new instance. This could be useful when wanting to run consecutive 'workers' with the same options. Example:

```
Public Sub ProgressBarTest()
    With New ProgressBar
        .Info1 = "Please wait..."
        .AllowCancel = True
        .BarColor = &H4D6A00
        .ShowTime = True
        .ShowType = vbModal
        Debug.Print .RunMacro(ThisWorkbook, "DoWork", .Self, 2000)
        Debug.Print .RunObjMethod(New Class1, "DoWork", .Self, 2000)
    End With
End Sub
```

7. I did not group the class members into a private type because I wanted to preserve the PascalCase names of the exposed properties while all variables are camelCase. Grouping the members under a UDT makes naming so much more difficult unless you have everything in just PascalCase or just camelCase.

---

Any feedback and suggestions are welcome! Thank you!

---

Any future updates can be found at [Excel-VBA-ProgressBar](https://github.com/cristianbuse/Excel-VBA-ProgressBar)

Comment: +1 if gif provided... (ok +1 anyway, this is a great question with clear motivation)

Comment: @Greedo Thanks! Did not occur to me to add a gif. Never did before. Just added one.

Comment: I really like how you've taken my concept and pushed it to the next level, well done! And thanks for the kind words too!

Comment: This is a great enhancement, its really useful how its able to run multiple procedures on the same ProgressBar instance. Also good how the Run function can take parameters. With the Reusable Progress Indicator I would refactor my [procedure into an object](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2020/11/19/from-macros-to-objects-the-command-pattern/), put the parameters into a factory method and then pass the object to the ProgressIndicator create method:  `ProgressIndicator.Create("Run", Class1.Create(Param1, Param2))`